# Angular2 Material2 <md-spinner> not showing but is working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

My assumption is that my css is not correct, but alas I cannot figure this out.

```html
<div *ngIf="loading">
  <md-progress-circle mode="indeterminate" color="warn">Loading...</md-progress-circle>
</div>
<md-list>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let incident of incidents">
    <h3 md-line> {{name}} </h3>
    <p md-line>
      <span>{{date}} > </span>
      <span>{{text}}</span>
    </p>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you linked one of the @angular/material themes into your project? I've found that some of the controls work fine, but others are completely broken without it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to make sure you're using a theme for @angular/material.

From the [getting started guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md):

> **Include the core and theme styles:**
>
> This is required to apply all of the core and theme styles to your
>   application. You can either use a pre-built theme, or define your own
>   custom theme.
>
> - See the [theming guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md) for instructions.

I've found using @angular/material *without* a theme to work only some of the time. Text inputs work but radiobuttons, checkboxes - and it appears the spinners - require a theme to work properly.

As noted in the quote, you can either use one of the provided themes (there's currently 6 provided) or create your own. The provided themes can be included in your css using `@import('~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/<theme>.css')`.

Answer (score 2):

For me fixing this properties helps

```
/deep/ .mat-progress-spinner circle, /deep/ .mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: white;
}
```

where `white` is your visible color of spinner

Answer (score 0):

Change:

[color]="'warn'" 
[mode]="'indeterminate'"

Use square brackets for binding.
As you are assigning strings directly you have to use " and '

Add this line to your index.html header

<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Square brackets are used for binding, but shouldn't matter if you're binding a string literal. `[color]="'warn'"` is identical to `color="warn"`

Comment: made a difference when I tested it... and it worked... Did you?

Comment: you can also bring in a default style by adding a line to styles.css if your using cli
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';

Comment: To the first; nope, no difference. It works for me without the brackets, or with. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36220057/1733526). Also, as a matter of pedantry to the second; that's a theme, which is not the default style. By definition, a default is used when nothing else is provided. @angular/material doesn't provide a default theme, hence having to link one manually.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a font-awesome spinner, and it was working but not visible because the FontAwesome css file hadn't fully loaded yet. The solution was to use npm [angular2-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fontawesome) rather than to link the css file in index.html.

Answer (score 0):

In my similar case, spinner not showing and not throwing errors on screen, even the tag is parsed, I tried misspelling tag and angular throw tag not expected...

The fix was to be sure that MatProgressSpinnerModule is imported in the application.
Once imported spinner showed up perfectly.

I am guessing why the tag is parsed while progress spinner module was still not imported and I suppose that tag is registered in another more general imported module, not sure which.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had installed material with `npm install --save @angular/material`

but I was missing
`ng add @angular/material`

Answer (score 0):

in your src/styles.css file add the following line:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```