# how to use angular2 i18n-x to localize properties constant value

Tags: angular, internationalization

I try to make localization of my *Angular2* application with [i18n-x form](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#translate-attributes). It works well for attributes:

```
<p-dialog i18n-header header="User Details"></p-dialog>
```

result is:

```
<trans-unit id="fe871da89ff54aecdb1d2981639c988f15b4d9ad" datatype="html">
   <source>User Details</source>
   <target/>
</trans-unit>
```

but when I try to apply it to *angular* ***property constant value***, it doesn't create any xml tags. For example:

```
<my-journal i18n-tableHeader [tableHeader]="'Users'">
</my-journal>
```

Does angular *i18n* support this kind of translations at all? If it doesn't, what is ***the right approach*** to make this?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Sincerely,

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: not really. But I realized that i18n definitely will not work with definitions like this: [tableHeader]="'Users'", because as long as we use property binding, "'Users'" is recognized by angular as code, not text. And because it is not a template text anymore, we should find a good solution for localization in code. So far, I have not found a solution that could be shared

Comment: Does the syntax bind-tableHeader="'Users'" i18n-bind-tableHeader="..." work? The bind-tableHeader should be the canonical form of [tableHeader] .

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [canonical form](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-target) of angular attribtute binding - it should work with angular 4.4.6 and typescript 2.3.4 too. I have proofed it with this environment:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 6.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

try this solution please - i hope it is helpfull:

```
<my-journal
 bind-tableHeader="'Users'"
 i18n-bind-tableHeader="header of table@@mytableheader">
</my-journal>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by "Johnny Svarog" in a comment, the solution by "FunThomas424242" kind of works, but is not necessarily a good idea:

Since `bind-tableHeader` is a property binding that takes an expression, the string has to be quoted, so the translations strings (with example translation to Spanish) look like this:

- `'Users'`, translated as `'Usuarios'` (does not work if `Usuarios` is provided without quotes)

But what we would really like is the following:

- `Users`, translated as `Usuarios`

Another alternative which is not perfect either is to use a "normal" DOM attribute to pass the string as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36220057/1805388):

```
<my-journal i18n-tableHeader tableHeader="Users">
</my-journal>
```

The problem with this is that it might have some side effects if `tableHeader` suddenly has some other meaning in a future version of HTML5. The way to avoid this in AngularJS 1.x used to be that bindings with dashes (`table-header`), for which HTML5 guarantees that it will not add new ones, were converted to camelCase for the component binding. AFAIK there is no such thing in Angular 2+.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405) gives reason to hope that more i18n features are coming some time next year.