# Angular 4 string parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a touch stumped on why my input parameters are being turned into numbers. 
I have this component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tile',
  templateUrl: './tile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tile.component.css']
})
export class TileComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() icon1: string;
  @Input() headerText1: string;
  @Input() mainText: string;
  @Input() footerText: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and the template:

```
<div class="widget widget-stats bg-green">
  <div *ngIf="icon1" class="stats-icon"><i class="fa {{icon1}}"></i></div>
  <div class="stats-info">
      <h4>Header - {{headerText1}}</h4>
      <p>Icon - {{icon1}}</p>
      <p>Main - {{mainText}}</p>    
      <p>Footer - {{footerText}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Passing these this from another component works:

```
<app-tile [headerText1]="43543" [mainText]="123456" [footerText]="243542354235" [icon1]="999"></app-tile>
```

But I want this:

```
<app-tile [headerText1]="TOTAL VISITORS" [mainText]="93%" [footerText]="243542354235" [icon1]="fa-users"></app-tile>
```

headerText1 fails at compile time because there's a space and if I remove it the value is never displayed and icon1 show NaN.

Why would these be treated as numbers when I've clearly defined them as strings?

Comment: You need to add string literal - check this post for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220027/how-to-pass-a-string-value-to-a-component-in-angular2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, to pass string literals try adding single quotes within the double quotes, an *expression*, like this:

```
<app-tile [headerText1]="'TOTAL VISITORS'" [mainText]="'93%'"
```

Comment: Legend! I didn't realise the type was inferred within the double quotes. Makes sense though. Thanks so much.