# Angular Routing By Expression

Tags: angular

I m new to Angular and learning the angular routing part

Here for the first and second router link, i have used static path and for the third one, i tried with expression and i have a input text box whose model is 'myRoute'.. i m trying to type 'third' in the textbox and the value is binding into the model 'myRoute' and i have a component, 'ThirdComponent', defined in the route, but it doesnt work

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]='myRoute'>
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li><a routerLink="first">First</a></li> 
     <li><a routerLink="second">Second</a></li>
     <li><a [routerLink]="['myRoute']">Third</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my route

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
  { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent },
  { path: 'third', component: ThirdComponent }
];
```

Here is the error message which i m receiving

*Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'myRoute'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'myRoute'*

And i m clicking the third component link only after i enter the text 'third' in the textbox

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @alokstar edited my question with error message.

Comment: did you try `<li><a [routerLink]="['/myRoute']">Third</a></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error message it seems that 'myRoute' has passed as string to the router whereas, in your router, you have path defined for 'third' not for 'myRoute'. Check the data-binding on 'myRoute'.

```
<a [routerLink]="myRoute">
```

should do it!

Comment: Thanks. it worked. thanks a lot. i m not able to accept this answer within 6 minutes of this post. will accept it later..

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you bind `routerLink` to the literal string `'myRoute'`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36220057/1009922). The following syntax binds `routerLink` to the property `myRoute` of the component class:

```
<a [routerLink]="myRoute">
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. thanks a lot. i m not able to accept this answer within 6 minutes of this post. will accept it later..

Comment: But just would like to know, this is the binding syntax and the one which i have used is called?? i m new to this.. so not having an idea , i just refered some website and included that way

Comment: You bound the `routerLink` property to the literal string `'myRoute'`. In my answer, it is bound to the property `myRoute`.